# Router de angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

tengo una serie duda que, he solucionado pero seguramente no sea la mejor opcion, mi caso es que tengo una ruta en angular tal asi

```
{ path: 'categorias/:cat', component: CategoriasComponent},
```

pero mi problema llega en que cuando entro a la ruta mirul.es/categorias/1 por ejemplo, al cambiar a miurl.es/categorias/2 no me actualiza los datos que tengo, es decir la funcionalidad que tiene es recoger la id de una categoria y sacar los producctos relacionados con dicha categoria pero aunque en la url la id cambie, los productos se mantienen, por tanto lo que he tenido que hacer es un setinterval

```
setInterval(()=> {
  if(this.categoriaId != this.rutaActiva.snapshot.params.cat){
    this.categoriaId = this.rutaActiva.snapshot.params.cat;
    this.obtenerArticulos(this.rutaActiva.snapshot.params.cat);
  }

 }, 300);
```

y no creo que esto sea muy efectivo, que forma tendria de hacer funcionar correctamente esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has implementado una solución ingeniosa, pero Angular provee de las herramientas necesarias para hacerlo de un modo más *integrado*:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, ...) {}

ngOnInit() {
  // en lugar de mirar el snapshot, nos suscribimos a los cambios
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
    this.categoriaId = params.get('cat');
    this.obtenerArticulos(this.categoriaId);
  });
  //... resto de código
}
```